# phpexcel reading an excel file decimal numbers are read incorrectly

Tags: decimal, phpexcel

I've got the value '9,2' (dutch notation of '9.2') within a cell of a .xlsx file, the cell has a 'general' number format. Also the value in the upper bar where you also view formulas says '9,2' When I read this cell with PHPExcel with ->getValue() I get '9,199999999999999'.

This is my code:

```
$oPhpReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($sFileType);
$aWorksheetNames = $oPhpReader->listWorksheetNames($sFileName);
$oPhpReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$oPhpReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($aWorksheetNames[0]);
$oPhpExcel = $oPhpReader->load($sFileName);
$oWorksheet = $oPhpExcel->getActiveSheet();
$oCell = $oWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($iCol,$iRow);
$sTempValue = $oCell->getValue();
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of computer rounding errors.... display it to 1 decimal place using number_format() or sprintf() and it will magically correct itself

Comment: Well, that would be a nice fix if I knew how many decimal places I had, but some numbers are with one others with two or three digits... And frankly, the computer doesn't have to round anything. There is a plain number in the cell, no calculations, just 9,2... can't be that hard...

Comment: But there isn't a "plain number" in the cell, there's a "float" value in the cell - which means that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems applies - "can't be that hard", yet every single programming language for digital computers that uses standard IEEE for floating point numbers I susceptible to this.... what you see in MS Excel __is__ a rounded format

Comment: Perhaps if you tried using `getFormattedValue()` (which returns the number reflecting the formatting mask) rather than `getValue()` (which returns the "raw" data value)

Comment: But why is it that every time I open my excel file I see the same number but PHPExcel makes something different of it? Some way or another I need the correct value filled in into the excelsheet in my PHP application. There should be a sollution. Or is it a bug in PHPExcel itself?

Comment: I tried using getFormattedValue() and this works, but only if the cell in excel is formatted accordingly. And I do not have any control over the excel file which is fed to my application...

Comment: This is __NOT__ a bug in PHPExcel, it is an issue with floating point representation in general on digital computers... but what is your php.ini [precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) set to?

Comment: `why is it that every time I open my excel file I see the same number?` - because MS Excel applies rounding/formatting when it displays the number

Comment: it is set to 14, what should this be?

Comment: It should be as high as you need for the precision you need to display but low enough not to show rounding problems of the type you were getting

Comment: I think the precision should be what ever Excel uses as precision, that is the only way the rounding will give the same result. Isn't there a way to query the precision of the excelfile from within PHP with PHPExcel?

Comment: You can read the sourcecode, and the Excel format specs, so there's nothing to stop you finding out for yourself, or from modifying the code if you find a way to do it

Comment: It is clear that it is not a bug on either php or PHPExcel, but PHPExcel should come with the solution for it out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I solved my problem now. Though I do not think this is a very neat solution, it is probably the only way.

I just figured I will never get numbers with more than 12 digits, only when PHPExcel get them wrong. So I round all my floats to 12 digit using number_format:

```
if ((is_numeric($sTempValue))&&(strpos($sTempValue,'.')))
{
    $sTempValue = rtrim(rtrim(number_format($sTempValue,12,',',''),'0'),',');
}
```

Comment: But please note - this is __NOT__ a PHPExcel bug, or even a PHP bug